# How to close inline help in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In `tmux`, <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> will open a view with inline help.

How can I close this view and get back to my session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press `q` to quit the help.

From the tmux man page:

> Typing ‘C-b ?’ lists the current key bindings in the current window; up and down may be used to navigate the list or ‘q’ to exit from it.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the key in the help page itself.

Comment: haha yes I tried that too... you'd think they'd put that at the top